# Is these a pair of diastereomer or identical compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, erratum

I attempted on this question (e) and found out that they are diastereomers, but the answer from the book is that they are identical. I worked out the configuration at each of the centres for the molecules then compare the results. If you find that one is RS and the other is SS then you'll know that they differ at only one stereo-centre and hence I think the book is wrong. I've got this question from [Solomons: Organic Chemistry, 11th edition.](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002536.html).

[image]

Comment: You are right, the left one is SS the right one is SR (if we keep Br-C to the left and F-C to the right in both isomers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the answer of the book is wrong? For the fisher projection, it is Diastereomer definitely.

[image]